# How to do an X[Y] data.table join, without losing an existing main key on X?

Tags: r, data.table

When joining data.tables X and Y using X[Y], X must have a key, which the key of Y uses to make the join. If X is a very big table and normally keyed on columns not used in the join, then the key of X needs to be changed for the join, and then restored back to the original key after the join. Is there an efficient way to do the join, without losing the original main key on X?

I have a large time-series environmental dataset DT (1M rows, 36 columns), as a data.table with key on the site and date columns. I need to do calculations on existing columns in DT and/or insert a new column, based an existing column, using a small lookup or recode table.

Here is a minimal example:

```
require(data.table)   # using v1.9.5

# main data table DT, keyed on site and date, with data column x
DT <- data.table(site = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=3),
                 date = rep(1:3, times=2),
                 x = rep(1:3*10, times=2),
                 key = "site,date")
DT
#    site date  x
# 1:    A    1 10
# 2:    A    2 20
# 3:    A    3 30
# 4:    B    1 10
# 5:    B    2 20
# 6:    B    3 30

# lookup table for x to y lookup, keyed on x
x2y <- data.table(x = c(10,20), y = c(100,200), key = "x")
x2y
#     x   y
# 1: 10 100
# 2: 20 200
```

To join the lookup table x2y with the main table DT, I set the DT key to "x":

```
setkey(DT,x)
```

Then the join works as expected.

```
DT[x2y]
#    site date  x   y
# 1:    A    1 10 100
# 2:    B    1 10 100
# 3:    A    2 20 200
# 4:    B    2 20 200
```

and I can use "y" from the lookup table in calculations or to create a new column in DT.

```
DT[x2y, y:=y]
#    site date  x   y
# 1:    A    1 10 100
# 2:    B    1 10 100
# 3:    A    2 20 200
# 4:    B    2 20 200
# 5:    A    3 30  NA
# 6:    B    3 30  NA
```

But now my time-series dataset DT is keyed on "x", and I need to set the key back to "site,date" for further use.

```
setkey(DT,site,date)
```

Is this approach (key X, join, then re-key X) the fastest way to do this when DT is very large (1M rows), or is there an equally efficient way to do this type of lookup join, without losing the original key on the big DT table?

Comment: Unrelated but 1MM rows is a very small data set, keying it should take less than a second. I've just tested on 7MM and it was less than a second.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, keying is fast, but perhaps significant if done many times. A reason for the question that I didn't mention is that I am writing some general functions to do calculations on large datasets using joins, and it would be preferable if the functions didn't change the keys or order of the data.tables passed as arguments, unless key columns changed of course.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I mentioned its unrelated. Though a little bird whispered me that your request is on the project list of `data.table` developers.

Comment: @DouglasClark, as David mentioned, joins using secondary keys is on the list. I'll update the post once managed. Filed [#1130](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1130) just to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With secondary keys implemented (since v1.9.6) and the recent bug fix on retaining/discarding keys properly (in v1.9.7), you can now do this using `on=`:

```
# join
DT[x2y, on="x"] # key is removed as row order gets changed.

# update using joins
DT[x2y, y:=y, on="x"] # key is retained, as row order isn't changed.
```

Answer (score 7):

*Update:* Thanks to a bug fix, this is no longer necessary. Please see the accepted answer.

---

I would join just `x`:

```
DT[,y:=x2y[J(DT$x)]$y]
```

The key of `DT` is retained here.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I look forward to a simpler and more intuitive syntax when joins on secondary keys are implemented, as mentioned by Arun. .

Comment: I just checked timing on this answer vs. my OP, for a 2 x 1e6 randomly-ordered DT dataset. The OP method (setkey, join, setkey) takes 522 ms and this answer takes 251 ms. So it is twice as fast as my OP approach. I also tried adding set2key(DT,x) to this answer's method, and it took 426 ms, meaning that set2key did not help, in present data.table 1.9.5.